# base64 is not encoding in ajax

Tags: ajax, html, base64, urlencode

I want to send base64 string through ajax 
I encoded it through JavaScript function escape

```
data =  escape"data:image/png;base64,iVBOR w0K+GgoAAAAN+SUhEUgAAAU oAA+ADmCAYAAAC+zgMwkAAAgAElEQ+VR4Xu1de3BVx3n");
```

It worksfine and encode it as

```
data%3Aimage/png%3Bbase64%2CiVBOR%20w0K+GgoAAAAN+SUhEUgAAAU%20oAA+ADmCAYAAAC+zgMwkAAAgAElEQ+VR4Xu1de3BVx3n
```

But when I send it through ajax

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://fiveriverstech.com',
type: 'POST',
data: "data="+data,
success: function(response){
                console.log(response)
                }
            });
```

It replaces the `+` sign whit white spaces 
as `data:data:image/png;base64,iVBOR w0K GgoAAAAN SUhEUgAAAU oAA ADmCAYAAAC zgMwkAAAgAElEQ VR4Xu1de3BVx3n`

How I can prevent to do this

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranasaani/hfkGL/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use `encodeURIComponent()` instead of `escape()`. `escape()` is not intended to be used for URLs and form data.

Even easier would be to use

```
data: { data: 'data:image/png;base64,...' }
```

in your `$.ajax()` options, without bothering to encode it; jQuery will take care of everything.